# Handle razor foreach when Model value comes null?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

This is my code:

```
 @foreach(var data in @Model.Article.ListImage)
 {
     @: Array.push("@data");
 }
```

ListImage is null. Yeah, i know... "create an if before or after validating if the Model is null", i did that but is still getting null on the foreach line.

There is a trick to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if(Model=!=null)
{
 foreach(var data in Model.Article.ListImage)
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the way: @if(Model.Article.ListImage != null) {
                                foreach(var data in Model.Article.ListImage) 
                                {